# Java - Error catching user-input with enums

Tags: java, error-handling, enums

I have defined an `enum` in java to use that for validating user input. I am having an issue where if the user puts in something the program just exits and doesn't loop that way I'm expecting it to.

I want to be able to loop until the user has inputted one of the items on the list.

Here's the code in question:

```
// import System.out
import static java.lang.System.out;

// import scanner for user-input
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalTest {

    // enum for user-input
    enum animal{

        COW,
        DUCK,
        PIG,
        SHEEP

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // create scanner for user input
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            // print out menu
            out.println("Which animal are you?\nCow\nDuck\nPig\nSheep");

            // get user-input and validate against enum
            try{
                
                animal selection = animal.valueOf(userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase());
            
            }
            catch (Exception e){

                out.println("Please type in one of the animals above.");

            }
            finally{
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        // switch based on validated user input
        switch(selection){

            case COW:

                cow cow0 = new cow();
                cow0.sound();
                break;

            case DUCK:

                duck duck0 = new duck();
                duck0.sound();
                break;

            case PIG:

                pig pig0 = new pig();
                pig0.sound();
                break;

            case SHEEP:

                sheep sheep0 = new sheep();
                sheep0.sound();
                break;

        }// end switch

    }// end main

}// end class
```

After this, I am going to use a `switch` and one of the errors the compiler is throwing at me is that the variable `selection` is not defined so I can use the `switch` on it, any insight on this aspect as well is apprciated

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes and enums start with an upper case letter (Animal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the problem highlighted by @mauvecrow's answer, your do/while is useless. a `finally` block ALWAYS runs, so your while loop will always break at the end. You might as well delete the break, and the entire 'while' construct. Perhaps you intended to loop until a correct answer is entered? Then put the break after the `selection =` line, **within** the `try` block.

Comment: thanks for your insight, I am new to java and am still getting used to the syntax!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that your "animal selection" variable is defined *locally* in the try block, thus it is out of scope by the time you get to the switch case.

I have this code (with minor changes for things to run for me) and it works. I declared and initialized (even initialization to null is fine) first.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

//import scanner for user-input
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalTest {

 // enum for user-input
 enum Animal{

     COW,
     DUCK,
     PIG,
     SHEEP

 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args){

     // create scanner for user input
     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     Animal selection = null;
     do {
         // print out menu
         out.println("Which animal are you?\nCow\nDuck\nPig\nSheep");

         // get user-input and validate against enum
         try{
             
             selection = Animal.valueOf(userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase());
         
         }
         catch (Exception e){

             out.println("Please type in one of the animals above.");

         }
         finally{
             break;
         }
     }
     while (true);

     // switch based on validated user input
     switch(selection){

         case COW:

             out.println("cow");
             break;

         case DUCK:

             out.println("duck");
             break;

         case PIG:

             out.println("pig");
             break;

         case SHEEP:

             out.println("sheep");
             break;
         default: out.println("not the expected animal");
         

     }// end switch

 }// end main

}// end class
```